# Запятая перед словом КАКИМ

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Нужна ли запятая?

"*От нас зависит каким будет завтра.*"

Answer (score 3):

Запятая ставится: **От нас зависит (то),  каким будет завтра.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с местоименно-определительным придаточным, указательное слово ТО пропущено, КАКИМ ― союзное слово.